# Como trabajar con datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, numpy

Mi problema es que no se como puedo hacer para trabajar con `datetime` pero mas rápido, cuando hago un `for` tarda casi 1 día en correr

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'fecha1': ["2018-3-3","2018-4-15"], 
                    'fecha2':["2018-02-31","2018-02-27"]})

df2["nueva"]=0
for i in range (len(df2)):
        If df2.fecha1.iloc[I] == "2018-3-3"
            Df2["nueva"].iloc[I]=df2.fecha1.iloc[I+1]-df2.fecha1.iloc[I]
        else:
            df2["nueva"].iloc[I]=0
```

No se si estoy usando mal el `for` o cuando resto al ser `datetime` con los 00:00:00 de seg y min tarda mucho, pero si lo hago en un `df` de cien mil `raws` tarda 1 día

Comment: Ayudanos a ayudarte. El código que has puesto contiene multitud de errores que hacen imposible ejecutarlo. Entre ellos: palabras reservadas que comienzan por mayúscula (`For`, `If`), ausencia de dos puntos tras el condicional, variables cuyo nombre no es consistente (`Df2` o `df2`, `I`o `i`), operaciones con tipos incorrectos (las fechas en tu ejemplo son cadenas, no son `datetime`, no pueden por tato restarse), acceso a elementos fuera de límite (`[i+1]`).... Si eso no funciona ¿como has podido probarlo y decir que tarda días? Pon tu verdadero código o un ejemplo mínimo que funcione.

Comment: @abulafia hola... El codigo lo hice con El celular, Las mayusculas serian minusculas ..  lo de [I+1] si bien queda fuera de rango... Funciona.. y datetime son esas fechas... Si podes pasarlo genial... Era solo un ejemplo rapido.. la pregunta es como es la mejor forma de trabajar con datetime.

Answer (score 0):

No está nada claro qué pretendes con el ejemplo, pues aparte de los errores sintácticos señalados en mi comentario la lógica es también confusa. Y contiene fechas inválidas, como un 31 de febrero. En fin, un desastre :-)

Aparentemente, quieres calcular la distancia entre dos fechas sucesivas de la columna `fecha1`, pero sólo si el valor de la fecha es "2018-3-3" y en otro caso el resultado sería cero, y asignar ese resultado a una nueva columna.

El código fallará si la fecha "2018-3-3" aparece la última, pues no hay fecha "siguiente" de la cual restar. Además de eso, la columna `fecha2` no participa en ningún momento, lo cual también parece raro.

Dices en el comentario que "solo era un ejemplo", de donde deduzco que éste no es el problema verdadero que pretendes resolver. Pero ese problema verdadero debe de existir, ya que mencionas que le lleva "casi un día" su ejecución. Sería mucho más productivo para todos que preguntaras por tu verdadero problema, en lugar de un ejemplo artificial cuya solución puede no tener nada qué ver con la del verdadero problema.

En todo caso, como norma general:

- Las fechas han de ser de tipo `datetime` si quieres operar con ellas (como calcular sus diferencias), y no de tipo "string" como las que estás usando, que no se pueden restar.
- Si puedes evitarlo **nunca iteres** por un DataFrame. Toda la potencia de Pandas viene de que él tiene sus propios iteradores mucho más rápidos. Si al final vas a hacer tus propios bucles no tiene sentido usar pandas y bien podrías tenerlo todo en una lista estándar Python. Pandas es capaz de hacer operaciones "vectoriales" entre columnas, como `df.a + df.b` por ejemplo que suma *cada elemento* de la columna `a` con *cada elemento*  de la columna `b`, sin que tengas que implementar ningún bucle que itere.

Dicho lo anterior, y a pesar de que este ejemplo es completamente artificial, paso a tratar de replicar tu pregunta, pero sin los errores lógicos.

Primero, crear un DataFrame con una sola columna (`fecha1`), ya que `fecha2` no sirve para nada en el ejemplo. Esta columna tendrá 100 entradas generadas al azar. Para ello escribo una función que retorne fechas de 2018, con el mes entre 1 y 4 y el día entre 1 y 10. Las fechas que genera esta función son cadenas, pero usando `pd.to_datetime()` las convierto a `datetime` para poder operar con ellas después:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

random.seed(2)   # Para que el resultado sea reproducible

def fecha_aleatoria():
  "Fecha aleatoria de los cuatro primeros meses de 2018, con el dia entre 1 y 10"
  mes = random.randint(1,4)
  dia = random.randint(1,10)
  return "2018-%02d-%02d" % (mes, dia)

fechas = pd.to_datetime([fecha_aleatoria() for i in range(100)])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'fecha1': fechas})
```

Este es el aspecto del dataframe (solo las cinco primeras filas):

```
      fecha1
0 2018-01-02
1 2018-01-06
2 2018-02-05
3 2018-03-10
4 2018-02-10
```

Haremos ahora lo que sugerías en el ejemplo, es decir, una nueva columna llamada `"nueva"` que tenga la resta entre la fecha siguiente y la actual, siempre que la actual sea `2018-03-03` (en este ejemplo esa fecha sólo aparece dos veces, por lo que el resultado será cero en casi todos los casos). Pero lo haremos **sin bucles**.

Lo más sencillo (y más rápido que usar bucles) es calcular la diferencia entre cada fila con la siguiente, sin tener en cuenta el valor de la fecha. Esto lo puede hacer Pandas vectorialmente en poco tiempo:

```
df2["nueva"] = df2.fecha1.shift(-1) - df2.fecha1
```

El operador `shift()` desplaza (en este caso una fila hacia arriba) toda la serie, y luego le restamos la otra serie `df2.fecha1`. El resultado tiene esta pinta:

```
      fecha1    nueva
0 2018-01-02   4 days
1 2018-01-06  30 days
2 2018-02-05  33 days
3 2018-03-10 -28 days
4 2018-02-10 -31 days
```

Ves como en la columna "nueva" tienes la distancia temporal entre esa fecha y la siguiente.

Ahora rellenaremos con cero todos los casos no deseados, que son aquellos para los que `fecha1` es diferente de `2018-03-03`, de nuevo **sin bucles**.

```
df2.loc[df2.fecha1 != pd.to_datetime("2018-03-03"), "nueva"] = 0
```

Mediante `loc[filas, columnas]` podemos seleccionar ciertas celdas del dataframe y a ellas les asignamos cero. Las filas seleccionadas son las que tienen fecha diferente de `2018-03-03`, y la columna es "nueva".

Este es el resultado (solo primeras cinco filas):

```
      fecha1 nueva
0 2018-01-02     0
1 2018-01-06     0
2 2018-02-05     0
3 2018-03-10     0
4 2018-02-10     0
```

No es muy interesante el resultado porque ninguna de esas fechas era la buscada. Pero aparece más adelante, en la fila 71:

```
       fecha1            nueva
70 2018-04-08                0
71 2018-03-03  2 days 00:00:00
72 2018-03-05                0
73 2018-03-10                0
74 2018-04-01                0
75 2018-02-01                0
```